# Why $route.current.params and $routeParams different?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I coded Angular Route for controller to catch parameter. The result makes me down.

configuration:

```
    .config(function ($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    });
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/products/insert/:id', {
            controller: 'ProductInsertCtrl'
        });
    })
```

test:

```
            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                console.log($route.current.params, $routeParams);
            });
```

result:

```
Object {}, undefined
```

shows us difference of $route.current.params and $routeParams. Why??? I need explanation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$route.current.params are the parameters you pass while resolving the route and $routeParams are parameters that are appended to url